# Flutter : PageView keep Stay in previous Screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I use PageView in my screen to Navigate to another screen. I have 3 screen `Home`,`History` and `History Detail`.

Everything is fine i can move to `history` screen. Until i redirect to `History Detail` from `History` Screen and i back with `Navigator.of(context).pop` , I redirect to `Home` Screen. I want after Back from `History Detail` i keep stay in `History` Screen.

I already initialize initialPage is **0** , and change the initialPage with `onPageChanged` but nothing happens, i still redirect to `Home` Screen.

How can i do for my case?

#### It's My Source Code.

```
  PageController _pageController;
  int currentPage = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: currentPage);
    super.initState();
  }

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    double mqHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: Hive.openBox("debt_box"),
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
            else
              return Scaffold(
                body: PageView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  onPageChanged: (index) {
                    currentPage = index;
                    print(currentPage);
                  },
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: _pageController,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CustomScrollView(
                      slivers: <Widget>[
                        SliverAppBarHome(),
                        SliverListHome(_scaffoldKey),
                      ],
                    ),
                    HistoryDebt(),
                  ],
                ),
              );
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Container(
          height: mqHeight * 0.08,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                onPressed: () =>
                    functionHelper.previousButtonPageView(_pageController),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.insert_chart),
                onPressed: () =>
                    functionHelper.nextButtonPageView(_pageController),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
  }
```

[image: Pageview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

When you press back button it re-builds your main widget. In the `build` method you have `FutureBuilder` which also gets rebuild.

So it will show you `CircularProgressIndicator`. Since `Hive.openBox("debt_box")` gives the result instantaneously, you are not able to see it.

While showing `CircularProgressIndicator` your `PageView` got deactivated (removed from widget tree). So `_pageController` loses its client.

After the `CircularProgressIndicator`, a new `PageView` gets created.

That is why it showed `Home` page

**Solution:**

As per the [document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) we should not directly assign `future: Hive.openBox("debt_box")` during the build. Instead create a `Future` variable and initialize it in the `initState`, then pass that variable to `future` property of `FutureBuilder`

```
PageController _pageController;
int currentPage = 0;
Future _openBox;

@override
void initState() {
  _pageController = PageController(initialPage: currentPage);
  _openBox = Hive.openBox("debt_box");  //initialize here
  super.initState();
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  double mqHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  return Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    body: FutureBuilder(
      future: _openBox, //pass the future variable here
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
      ...
```

Comment: I used navigator.of(context).pushNamed(). I will try change to `Navigator.of(context).push`

Comment: Its fine to use either of them

Comment: @ZeffryReynando I update my answer. Ask if you have further queries

Comment: So my `_pageController` will always refresh and re-create again when i back from `history` screen , because in my `home` screen have `FutureBuilder` ? it's no solution except i removed the `futurebuilder` ?

Comment: When do you exactly want to call Hive.openBox("debt_box")?. Only once (at the beginning) or every time you do some action?

Comment: it's only once, i should dispose `Hive.openBox()` it in `home` screen but i will do it later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204556/discussion-between-vijayaragavan-and-zeffry-reynando).

Comment: It's work ! . 
So if i directly create future inside `Futurebuilder` it will rebuild ?

Comment: yes. If you use the future function directly, it will get called again and again when widget rebuilds

Answer (score 0):

**Try/Route with this on Your History page**

```
 Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourDestination()));
```